# Partial ArcGIS for Server Caching?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, cache

I have a Map Services layer that covers the United States and I'd like it to be cached between the scales of say 18M and 288K, and then from 288K to 1K, I just want to draw dynamically (because it would take up too much space to cache it).

Can this be done, splitting it up like that?

I'm still on ArcGIS 10.1 for Server.

Comment: Not sure if this can be done on a single service, but you could have 2 services - one cached that turns off at 288K and the other dynamic that turns on at 288K

Comment: Why not cache at scales >18M ? They won't take up much space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create an empty tile cache, then use the [Manage Tile Cache tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/manage-tile-cache.htm), you should be able to check off and generate only the tiles in your scales of interest before executing the tool.

Comment: That will give me the cached tiles that I want, but then how do I get the tiles that I don't want cached to still show up in the map? Do as Midavalo says and create 2 services?

Comment: You shouldn't need two services - but you would need two different layers that use that layer as a source: the [ArcGISDynamiceMapServiceLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer-amd.html) and the [ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/arcgistiledmapservicelayer-amd.html) would both use the same url.

Comment: OK, I see, let me give that a go...thx